# Macro code to create mutile pivot in same sheet

Tags: excel

I have created a macro code where in only one pivot table gets created, can some one help me in creating mutilple pivot table in single sheet.

The below code i am using, here the filter selects only for india, in next H column i want the same pivot table where in it selects EMEA

and in next Q column the filter selects others

code:

```
Sub pivottable()
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache1 As PivotCache
Dim PTable As pivottable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable2")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Raw Data")

LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="PivotTable")

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")

Sheets("PivotTable").Select

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Region")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Region").CurrentPage = _
        "INDIA"


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Assignment Group")
 .Orientation = xlRowField
 .Position = 1


 End With



 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Aging")
 .Orientation = xlColumnField
  .Position = 1
  End With

  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
  "PivotTable").PivotFields("Number"), "Count of Number", xlCount
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Assignment group"). _
        AutoSort xlDescending, "Count of Number"




End Sub
```